# How big should my nvarchar column be to store a maximum 255 characters?

Tags: sql-server, unicode

I need to store 255 characters in a database column of type nvarchar. They characters are UTF-8 and can be multibyte. I am not the best with character encodings, so I'm not sure if that makes sense. I want to hold 255 characters that can be in any language, etc.

Comment: i'm faily certain that nvarchar(255) should be fine.

Comment: `nvarchar` stores data as UTF-16, not UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

You can find some simple-to-understand background information about different Unicode encodings in [this](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-maintenance-guide/internationalisation.html), which is a chapter I wrote in a manual for an open-source project. That background information will help you to understand some of the details in my answer.

The link to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) about `nvarchar` provided by Simmo states that `nvarchar` is stored in UCS-2 format. Because of this, you will need to convert the UTF-8 strings into UCS-2 strings before storing them in the database. You can find C++ code to do that conversion [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/utfConvert.aspx).

A subtle but important point is that the conversion code will actually convert into UTF-16, which is a superset of UCS-2 (UTF-16 supports the use of surrogate pairs, while UCS-2 doesn't). I don't use SQL Server so I don't know if it will complain if you try to insert some surrogate pairs into it. (Perhaps somebody else here can confirm whether or not it will).

*If* SQL Server disallows surrogate pairs, then there will be a limit on the range of languages your application can support, but at least you know that `nvarchar(255)` is sufficient for your needs.

On the other hand, *if* SQL Server allows the use of surrogate pairs, then you might want to use `nvarchar(510)` to allow for the (remote) possibility that every single character will be composed of surrogate pairs.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx

255 characters.